# Handle special characters in csv file for uploading it using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have a few special characters like üģï etc in one of the columns in the `.csv` file. I am trying to upload this file to the server using Angular, however the request is not reaching the API and it throws an error.

Please suggest any way out.

I tried encoding with `reader.readAsText(file, encoding)` and also defined BOM like

```
Data:text/csv,charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI()
```

but nothing is solving the issue.